# Showing that $\bigg\| x - \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_ke_k\bigg\| \geq \bigg\|x-\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k \bigg\|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

**Exercise :**

> Let $\{e_1,e_2,\dots, e_n\}$ be an orthonormal set over the Hilbert space $H$. Show that : 
>    $$\bigg\| x - \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_ke_k\bigg\| \geq \bigg\|x-\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k \bigg\|$$
>   for every $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n \in \mathbb R$.

**Attempt :**

Let $x \in H$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then,  we can find $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb R$ such that :

$$\bigg\| x - \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_ke_k\bigg\| < \varepsilon$$

But the element $w = x-\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ achieves the minimum distance of $x$ from the finite dimensional space $ F = \langle e_1,\dots, e_n \rangle$ and then it will be

$$\bigg\| x-\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k \bigg\| \leq \bigg\| x - \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_ke_k\bigg\| < \varepsilon$$

and thus the inequality which we were asked to show is proven.

**Question :** Is my approach rigorous and legit enough ? If not, any recommendations, hints or elaborations will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Just a remark: Since $\{e_n\}$ is a fixed orthonormal set, you might not be able to make the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k e_k$ arbitrarily close to $x$ in norm (which your solution seems to suggest since you're using $\epsilon$).

Comment: @MisterRiemann If that's the case, how would my proof be altered ? I assume that since $\{e_n\}$ is orthonormal then it would also be an orthonormal basis of the finite dimensional space $F$.

Comment: I think that your idea is correct, i.e. you should use the fact that the projection of $x$ onto $F$ is indeed the closest point to $x$ in $F$. I'm just saying that you should remove $<\epsilon$ in your argument (I don't even see the necessity for it). But let's wait for an answer from someone more knowledgeable than myself.

Comment: @MisterRiemann I just elaborated using $\varepsilon$ to show that the expression has some essence (meaning it wouldnt diverge).

Comment: You're dealing with a finite sum, so there are no problems with convergence (just apply the triangle inequality if you really want to convince yourself).

Comment: @MisterRiemann I get what you're saying, then it really is straightforward since the other distance is the smallest one anyway (or equal in case of being the same minimum distance).

Comment: Yes! Depending on the results that you have already proven, this can be considered to be straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $r = x - \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i$ is orthogonal to each vector $e_i$. If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb R$, then
\begin{align}
\| x - \sum_i \lambda_i e_i \|^2 &=
\|x - \sum_i \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i + \sum_i \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i - \sum_i \lambda_i e_i \|^2 \\
&= \| r + \sum_i (\langle x, e_i \rangle - \lambda_i) e_i \|^2 \\
&= \|r\|^2 + \sum_i | \langle x, e_i \rangle - \lambda_i | \|e_i\|^2 \qquad \text{(by Pythagorean theorem)}\\
& \geq \|r\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and swift algebraic proof.

Comment: @Rebellos Sure. This proof is based in my mind on a picture. We know that the point $x^* = \sum_i \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i$ has the property that $x - x^*$ is orthogonal to the subspace $S  = \text{span}(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$. So, any other vector in $S$ must be further away from $x$, according to the Pythagorean theorem.